# Design Pattern Bridge in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, bridge

I am needing to implement in Java using the Bridge pattern to separate two hierarchies that will address different aspects of an object. We want to implement ordered lists and unordered and can be printed as numbered items, letters or markers ("*", "-", etc..).

Tip: set abstraction (hierarchy from left) as one of a list that declares methods add (String s) and print () and their implementations (refined abstractions) interface would be the ordered list and unordered. As implementer (hierarchy from right), define an interface that prints list items, and their implementation would be responsible for printing with numbers, letters, labels, etc..

I do not know how, nor where to start. Could you help me?

Comment: Start with one of the hierarchies. Once complete, move the the other hierarchy and then 'bridge' them by modifying the base class in one of the hierarchies.

Comment: Also, look at the gang of four design patterns book, there is a good diagram in it. If you don't have this book then google 'bridge pattern'. There are plenty of good example on the net.

Comment: I will search. I do not have the book

Comment: Great, have a go at it and then if you have any more specific questions then i'm happy to answer them :)